# Can't fetch the column data even after successful execution of query

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql

Here is snippet of my code

```
   $query="SELECT cid,city_name FROM city_trade WHERE city_name LIKE '$num' OR pin='$num'";
   $res=pg_query($query);
   if (!$res) {
     echo "Data Not found for this City"; exit;
   }else{
     $id=pg_fetch_assoc($res)['cid'];
     $name=pg_fetch_assoc($res)['city_name'];
     var_dump($id);
     var_dump($name);
   }
```

And I am getting `$name` as `NULL` and `$id` is correct. 
Why `city_name` is not coming after successful execution of query ? 
And how we can fetch it without using an extra query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only getting one result but you're trying to fetch two rows from your result set. You only need to call `pg_fetch_assoc()` once to get your result set and then you can access the values you want from there:

```
// Get results of query in an associative array
$row  = pg_fetch_assoc($res);
// Get each desired value
$id   = $row['cid'];
$name = $row['city_name'];
```